# PHP storing file name from HTML for and saving to variable

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, file-upload

I am uploading a file to a server through an HTML form and then emailing the HTML form content to myself. I can store all the form values into PHP variables like this...

```
$name = strip_tags($_POST["name"]); 
$email = strip_tags($_POST["email"]);
$phone = strip_tags($_POST["phone"]);
```

but can not store the file name of the uploaded file in the same way. ex..

```
$uploadFile0 = strip_tags($_POST["uploadFile0"]);
```

I'm storing the file(s) to my server using a loop.

```
$i = 0;
    while(isset($_FILES['uploadFile'. $i])){
       echo 'item' . $i . 'present';
        $file_name = $_FILES['uploadFile'. $i]['name'];
        $file_name = stripslashes($file_name);
        $file_name = str_replace("'","",$file_name);
        $copy = copy($_FILES['uploadFile'. $i]['tmp_name'], $folderPath . $file_name);
        if($copy){
            echo "$file_name | uploaded sucessfully!<br>";
        }else{
            echo "$file_name | could not be uploaded!<br>";
        }
        $i++;
    };
```

Basically I want to capture the name of the file to a variable and echo it out in an email. I have a feeling I'm staring at the answer but I just can't put it together. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: isn't `$file_name` the name of the file?

Comment: Uploaded files in PHP **NEVER** appear in the _POST array. They're only in _FILES, so you'd want `$_FILES['uploadFile']['name']` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will `$_FILES['uploadFile'. $i]['name']` not give you the name of the file?

Or just to grab the first one `$_FILES['uploadFile0']['name']`

Comment: That's it. I just had to create the variables like this $uploadFile0 = $_FILES['uploadFile0']['name'];
 $uploadFile1 = $_FILES['uploadFile1']['name'];
 $uploadFile2 = $_FILES['uploadFile2']['name'];